# how to make slideshow with arows automatic slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have tested the slideshow annd it is working fine with no issue. i want the slideshow to be like this multiple slideshow (slideshow 1 and slideshow 2) with next and previous buttons. but i wnat to add automatic sliding between images feature for it, thank you.

```html
<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="img_band_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval with click() is solution:

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}

// update    
setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow-container .next').forEach(function (item) {
        item.click();
    });
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598821825527-52c94deba7ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598523959079-da7b0e3d7b39?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599685590685-d5d801ec4a63?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600450575743-43793ba079d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600113719447-11944b2d2055?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```